# Information about resources in a subscription

Tags: azure

Good morning,

I've been trying to get information about all the resources in a given Azure subscription. Is there a way to see all the resources hosted in a subscription?

Comment: Go to portal --> Find your Azure Subscription --> Click on Resources. You should see all of your resources there.

Comment: @GauravMantri You can add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running [Az-GetResource via PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresource?view=azps-3.4.0)

First [Install Az Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-3.4.0)

Then would run

```
Connect-AzAccount
```

Then after the Pop Up asking to login

```
Get-AzResource | ft
```